# Save current Collection<T> in loop

Tags: c#, collections

I have some problems with collection lists. I use the list for saving some customer data which i collect from xml and textfiles.

```
// First i create an instance of the list  
List<Customer> cusList = new List<Customer>();
// Save files
String[] somefiles = Directory.GetFiles(//FromPath");

// Then i loop through some files and collect data for the list
for (int i=0; i<somefiles.length; i++)
{
    if (some statements match)
    {
        // call a methode and save file data to the cuslist
        cuslist= callmethode(somefiles);
    }
    else 
    {
     System.Console.WriteLine("Do nothing");
    }
 }
```

I want to extend the list for all files, but at the moment i get after the loop only data from the last file.

How can i handle it, that it saves all the data from all files?

Kind regards

Comment: Your pseudo code really doesn't help us understand what you're trying to achieve or where your problem lays.

Comment: Are your files in a list or something equivalent? You can use `foreach` to loop through all files if that's the case.

Comment: File iterating was no problem, the only thing was to save the list correct. But now already solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `cuslist= callmethode(file);` you re-assign the list at every iteration. What you need instead is something like this:

```
cuslist.AddRange(callmethode(file));
```

This will just add the elements returned from the method to your list instead of replacing the entire list.

If the method just returns one single element use `cuslist.Add` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! That was what i searched for =)

Answer (score 4):

[HimBromBeere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996653/284240) explained the issue and provided the correct answer, just as a side-note:

You could use LINQ to simplify this task:

```
List<Customer> cusList = somefiles
    .Where(f => some statements match)
    .SelectMany(f => callmethode(f))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: OP has also an `else` (which is currently dumped out however). For that to handle you´d have to re-iterate the list.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: i know, but since he just prints that this "does nothing", i guess that he just wanted to point out that this branch is a no op.

Comment: Nice approach thank you! I used the solution upside and keep yours in mind.